# How to reload page on submitting a button in the modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I am a beginner I am using php and javascript. I want to refresh the page view_create_journals.php when I click on the change button in the modal. I add a function to the change button but it's not working. I badly stuck here. Please give me some advice how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance guys. Codes are given below :

view_created_journals.php

```
        <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-info" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="color:black;font-size: 16px;">Plantation Journal Entry Basic Details</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form method="post">
                        <div class="table-repsonsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table1">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Journal No.</th>
                                        <th>Range</th>
                                        <th>Beat</th>
                                        <th>Scheme</th>
                                        <th>Year</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Change Status</th>
                                        <th>View</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php 
                                    $query="select * from plantation_journal_basic_details";
                                    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
                                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                        $plantation_journal_no=$row['plantation_journal_no'];
                                        $ranges=$row['ranges'];
                                        $beat=$row['beat'];
                                        $scheme=$row['scheme'];
                                        $year=$row['year'];
                                        $status=$row['status'];
                                        echo "<tr>
                                                    <th style='font-weight:300'>$plantation_journal_no</th>
                                                    <th style='font-weight:300'>$ranges</th>
                                                    <th style='font-weight:300'>$beat</th>
                                                    <th style='font-weight:300'>$scheme</th>
                                                    <th style='font-weight:300'>$year</th>
                                                    <th style='font-weight:300'>$status</th>
                                                    <th><a  name='view' id='view' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#change'>Change Status</a></th>
                                                    <th><a  href='all_details.php?id=".$row['plantation_journal_no']."' name='view' id='view' class='btn btn-info btn-sm'>View</a></th>
                                                </tr>";
                                                if(isset($_POST['status'])){
                                                    $status=$_POST['status'];
                                                    $sql1="UPDATE plantation_journal_basic_details SET status='$status' where plantation_journal_no='$plantation_journal_no';";
                                                    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
                                                }
                                    }?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="modal fade" id="change" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Change Status</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="view_created_journals.php" method="post">
                <label>Status : </label>
                <select name="status" id="status">
                    <option value="Committed">Committed</option>
                    <option value="Edit and Submit">Edit and Submit</option>
                    <option value="Edited and Submitted">Edited and Submitted</option>
                    <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
                </select><br><br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="myFunction()" name="submit_change">Change</button>
        </form>
        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            location.reload();
        }
        </script>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What function are you talking about?

Comment: @Samuel myFunction()

Comment: @Samuel the code u have given it's not refreshing the page on clicking the change button

Comment: Do you see anything on your web console?

Comment: @Samuel no I don't see anything in the console.

Comment: I've updated my answer. see if that makes a difference

Comment: @Samuel no it's also not helping

Comment: I don't see why you are using a javascript function to reload the page when that will happen "for free" just by submitting the form.

Comment: @James is right... But I am not really sure how this would not be working... it's vanilla js

Comment: @James I am submitting the form in the modal and I want to reload the page. Please give me some solution how to resolve this.

Comment: Are you trying to reload part of the page or the whole page?  If the whole page, just submit the form and the whole page will reload.  Otherwise you'll probably need to do your form submit by ajax.

Comment: @James I want to refresh the whole page but just by submitting the form it's not done.

Comment: You have to explain what *does* happen.  You have some other problems with that php, like you're updating every row in the database whenever a status is posted, I doubt that's intended.  It makes trying to guess at a solution very difficult when the code doesn't make sense.

Comment: @James I have explained enough. You didn't get it, that is not my fault. And the code makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your page should automatically be refreshing when you `POST` the form. That's default. Specially as it doesn't seem you are using any sort of `ajax` functions.

Nonetheless, to refresh a page you really need to use JavaScript. PHP runs when you're requesting a page, and javascript is what gives you all the changing elements in your browser.

Once the page is loaded PHP stops, it doesn't do anything new. That's where JS comes in. You can make the page interactive with Javascript.

To reload a page in JS:

```
window.location.reload();
```

---

This will reload the page. More specific in you case:

You have this button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit_change">Change</button>
```

Add this script at the bottom of your script:

```
<script>
  document.querySelector('input[name=submit_change]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    window.location.reload();
  });
</script>
```